# Clock IC Layout

Tags: integrated-circuit, clock

I would like to know how to implement a oscillator (~1MHz) on an IC chip. I want it to output a high-low signal, like PWM. I think I can do this by using a [Colpitts oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator) and then feeding it through an on-chip op amp, but I have no idea if that would work or be reliable at IC scale.

I am using the Magic IC layout editor on Ubuntu Linux. Please note, I am not willing to spend any money on software, as I'm only doing IC layout as a hobby.

Comment: First design the circuit (schematic). Then worry about the layout after you've done that.

Comment: Maybe you need to start with an idea for oscillator, what kind, how do you plan to get a stable frequency (if any), then define/calculate  input-output parameters?

Comment: before any design starts, the designer or customer writes specs to verify that the design works as expected. f error budget for temp, supply and mfg tolerances, jitter, SNR etc are all critical for some users. so please make an effort to write a simple list of specs. This is 60 yr old technology at least now made for under a dollar better than you can design.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question to make myself more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A current-starved ring oscillator is a useful starting point if you want any sort of control over the frequency.

[image: cs ro 5-stage]

You can control the speed by changing the bias voltage on the header/footer FET's.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid any analog signals, you can put multiple FET's in parallel as header/footer devices (on each stage of the ring oscillator) and digitally control them.

Of course, as is, the frequency is going to drift based on lots of factors (voltage, temperature, etc).  For that you will need feedback or some more complex circuitry.

Comment: Thanks, but just to make sure: the voltage on the loop is the output, right?

Comment: Yes.  But any node can be used as the output since they form an oscillating ring

Comment: Okay, one last thing: can you give an example of a feedback circuit for this? Thanks again.

Comment: @Anonymous1847: An example of feedback is some circuitry to moniter the output frequency and adjust the bias voltage (Va) to keep the frequency steady and at a specific value.  This is not a trivial task (especially if the voltage varies).

Answer (score -4):

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/epson/SG5032CAN-1.000000M-TJGA3/SER3937CT-ND/5175029

SMD 1 MHz oscillator chip  $1.23 usd   (1pc) stock  1.6~3.3V  50ppm -40~85'C
[image]

or 100ppm $2.37
[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: doh! thanks for the obvious Photon.  Perhaps he is not willing to spend any money building an IC as well. let him decide